# Did Man-Hobbit marriages ever happen?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In Tolkien's Middle-earth, Men and Hobbits lived together amicably at Bree, but I recollect no suggestion in *The Lord of the Rings* that the Big and Little People ever intermarried despite sharing a common culture. Elves and Men, who Tolkien considered to be more different from each other than Hobbits and Men, did intermarry on very rare occasions, and could have children. Presumably a Man and Hobbit could have children together. In any of his extensive writings, did Tolkien ever mention a marriage between a Man (male or female) and a Hobbit?

Comment: Cartoon Gandalf doesn't rule it out. "...Humans might well wonder 'Is there Hobbit in me?' " https://youtu.be/kf3RLq_j2wg

Comment: It would be amusing if the rumored "fairy ancestor" of the Tooks was actually a Druaden, one of the short strange men, and one of the ancestors of that particular Druadan was a more or less typical human, and one of the ancestors of that more or less typical human was a Numenorean, and one of the ancestors of the Numenorean was a member of the royal family descended from Elros.  Elros was descended from the chiefs of the 3 houses of the Edain, from Sindar, Noldor, and Vanyar Eleves, and from Melian the Maia.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Stranger things have happened. I can trace my ancestry to Charlemagne, but it's a long and bumpy ride in between, and I don't expect to inherit the Holy Roman Empire anytime soon.

Comment: This is more a matter of physics than genetics.  A Wolf and a Chihuahua are genetically compatible.

Comment: @lucasbachmann The difference in stature between Men and Hobbits wasn't supposed to be that extreme. Aside from that, you may be interested to read more about human dwarfism [here](http://understandingdwarfism.com/),

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, but Tolkien has discussed Hobbits intermarrying with other races

Dating back to one of the original surviving drafts of the opening to The Hobbit, we have a concept that there was at least one Took-Hobbit who married an elf.

> It had always been said that long ago some or other of the Tooks had married into a fairy family (goblin family said severer critics); certainly there was something not entirely hobbitlike about them, and once in a while members of the Took hobbits would go and have adventures.

This passage was retained with some minor changes into the original published book:

> It had always been said that long ago one or other of the Tooks had married into a fairy family (the less friendly said a goblin family); certainly there was still something not entirely hobbitlike about them, and once in a while members of the Took-clan would go and have adventures.

Though after some later revisions, the current third edition text now plays this down a bit specifying that is "absurd".

> It was often said (in other families) that long ago one of the Took ancestors must have taken a fairy wife. That was, of course, absurd, but certainly there was still something not entirely hobbitlike about them, and once in a while members of the Took-clan would go and have adventures.

The abandoned "1960 Hobbit", would have also kept it, just with the language changed to be a bit more in the line with *The Lord of the Rings*.

> It was often said (in other families) that the Tooks must have some elvish blood in them: which was of course absurd, but there was undoubtedly some thing queer about them, something not quite hobbitlike, according to the manners of the Shire: an outlandish strain maybe from long ago.

Comment: In early versions of the lengendarium like the Book of LostTales, there were actually fairies separate from Elves.  So as long as fairies remained part of the legendarium, and I don't known when or if they were excluded, a hobbit-fairy marriage would have been theoretically possible.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Are you sure about that? Most things I'm seeing from BoLT seem to point that fairies *are* elves.

Comment: @M.A.Golding In the same way that Gwendeling (=Melian) was a "fay" in BoLT, the terminology pre-mid-30s can be quite surprising

Comment: @ibid Thank you for a thoughtful answer. It's interesting that Tolkien phased out the fairies. Unlike C. S. Lewis, he seems to have deliberately limited the variety of humanoids in his work. (One wonders how centaurs, satyrs, fauns, etc. would have lived alongside humans and talking animals in Narnia.)

Comment: Do you think that by goblin he meant, at this time, an Orc? Or were they separate beings at the time of writing these revisions?

Comment: @Wade - In all of these quotes goblin=orc and fairy=elf.

Comment: @ibid So was he suggesting people thought Took willingly married an Orc, or that there was some rape in the past? I was not aware that Tolkien ever thought of Orcs breeding with other creatures, except by force.

Comment: @Wade - I don't think it's worth thinking that deep into a hobbit remark intended as an insult, but I interpreted this as consensual. That said, you probably shouldn't put too much stock into the fairy comment either. It's just Hobbits trying to rationally explain why the Took family is so weird and constantly going off on adventures. But it's the closest source I can think of for this question.

Comment: @ibid Yes, I think you're right. I'd say that in practice Tolkien didn't really think seriously of Hobbit interracial marriages...